# Java array removal gives unexpected results?

Tags: java, arrays

The following code is part of a program which takes the values of array ar except for variable z, and copies it onto a different array called ar2. The result should be all the numbers except negative two (19, 1, 17, 17), but currently the result is 19 1 17 17 -2 19 1 17 17 -2 19 1 17 17 -2 19 1 17 17 -2.

```
public class Second_tiny {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ar = { 19, 1, 17, 17, -2 };
        int z = ar[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < (ar.length); i++) {
            if (z > ar[i]) {
                z = ar[i];

            }
        }
        // second pass
        int[] ar2 = new int[ar.length];
        int zero = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < (ar.length); x++) {
            if (ar[x] == z) {
                continue; // If it is equal to z go back to the loop again

            }
            ar2[zero++] = ar[x];

            for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(ar[i]);
            }
            /*
             * //2nd pass copy all items except smallest one to 2nd array int[] ar2= new int[ar.length-1]; int curIndex = 0; for (i=0; i<ar.length; i++) { if (ar[i]==z) continue; ar2[curIndex++] =
             * ar[i]; }
             */

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you fix up the formatting in your IDE? Most likely the bug will be more obvious if you arrange the code in a readable manner.  I would also step through your code in your debugger to see what the issue is.  Most likely you are not resetting a variable between loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing out your original array 4 times in this block:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(ar[i]);
}
```

That block should be outside of your loop, and should reference `ar2` instead of `ar`.

```
for (int x = 0; x < (ar.length); x++) {
    if (ar[x] == z) {
        continue; // If it is equal to z go back to the loop again
    }

    ar2[zero++] = ar[x];
}

for (int i = 0; i < ar2.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(ar2[i]);
}
```

This will give you the following result:

```
19
1
17
17
0
```

The last `0` appears because `0` is the default value for `int`s. Your `ar2` array is 5 elements long, and for the last element the default value is never replaced.

Comment: Thank you, after doing this, I got a result of:

Comment: 19
1
17
17
0
Why has variable z been replaced with 0

Comment: Is there a way to have ar2 a default number of elements long, so that the zeros would never come, even if I had multiple negative 2's. Now, if my original array was to have multiple of the lowest integer, I would get multiple o's.

Comment: The easiest way would be to put your results (`ar2`) into an `ArrayList` instead of an array, and then convert back to an array after processing. Also, the [Java 8 solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31911728/3558960) proposed by @sibnick will work.

Comment: Thank you Robby, I might also be able to find the length of numbers that are not zero's by using a for loop and if statement, and subtract that length from ar.length, instead of doing ar.length-1.

Comment: Yeah, but that's only assuming you don't have zeroes in your original input array.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 way:

```
        int[] ar = { 19, 1, 17, 17, -2 };
        int min = Arrays.stream(ar).min().getAsInt();
        int[] ar2 = Arrays.stream(ar).filter(s -> s!=min).toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Math.min(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29) to determine your lowest value. Your second array should be one element smaller. I suggest guarding against removing more than one value. And you could use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) to print the *second array*. Something like,

```
int[] ar = { 19, 1, 17, 17, -2 };
int z = ar[0];
for (int i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
    z = Math.min(z, ar[i]);
}
// second pass
int[] ar2 = new int[ar.length - 1];
boolean first = true;
for (int x = 0; x < ar.length; x++) {
    if (ar[x] == z && first) {
        first = false;
        continue; // If it is equal to z go back to the loop again
    }
    int y = x - (!first ? 1 : 0);
    ar2[y] = ar[x];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar2));
```

Output is

```
[19, 1, 17, 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]you code is right mistakenly you have given one extra for loop.i have done comment on that for loop.use the following code u will get the desired output.

public class HelloWorld {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ar = { 19, 1, 17, 17, -2 };
        int z = ar[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < (ar.length); i++) {
            if (z > ar[i]) {
                z = ar[i];

            }
        }
        // second pass
        int[] ar2 = new int[ar.length];
        int zero = 0,i=0;

        for (int x = 0; x < (ar.length); x++) {
            if (ar[x] == z) {
                continue; // If it is equal to z go back to the loop again

            }
            ar2[zero++] = ar[x];

          //  for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(ar[i]);
                i++;
          //  }
            /*
             * //2nd pass copy all items except smallest one to 2nd array int[] ar2= new int[ar.length-1]; int curIndex = 0; for (i=0; i<ar.length; i++) { if (ar[i]==z) continue; ar2[curIndex++] =
             * ar[i]; }
             */

        }

    }
}
```

output is:

```
19

1

17

17
```

Comment: Thank you, this gets me a result of 19 1 17 17 0, because ar2 has already been given a default number of values, which is equal to the values of the first array. Is there any way I can get rid of this zero, even if I had multiple smallest numbers in my original array.

Comment: i am not getting any 0 in my output. @Rich

Comment: @PiyushMittal You're skipping it in your output, but it's still present in your result array.

Comment: I repeat my previous comment.